# Exposing Web API controller in external Dot Net Framework library from ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core web app (Dot Net Framework) in VS2017 for my REST Web API interface and I want to expose a controller defined in my external Dot Net Framework 4.5 library. I've added a reference to the library but the web app doesn't discover it. The library reference appears to be OK because I can create instances of other classes that are defined in it. I have no problems exposing the controller from an ASP.NET (DNF) web app.

I've also created a controller in the web app project that derives from ApiController (rather than Controller) but it doesn't get discovered either.

How do I get the web app to discover the external controller? Could I get it working using WebApiCompatShim?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "Dot Net Framework". Generally, you have ".NET Framework", but that's a huge umbrella that covers a lot of stuff. Importantly, underneath that umbrella, you have things like .NET Core, .NET Framework (colloquially the "Full Framework"), .NET Standard, etc. It sounds like you're attempting to reference a Full Framework library in a Core application running on the Core Framework. If so, that's not possible. The Core app must be running on the Full Framework, as well, or your library needs to target a version of .NET Standard like 1.4, which is compatible with .NET Core.